# How to detect available free memory in golang?

Tags: go, memory-management

In os package there is Getpagesize() to get the current os memory page size. Is there any way to get the number of unallocated (free) pages / unallocated memory in bytes and the total (unallocated+allocated)?

Comment: There's no platform-independent way of doing this. You'll be stuck relying on whatever information you can get from the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Collate some results here for available memory

as per comment it is platform dependent

For Windows

from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30743623/1409784) its possible to call a windows dll

in the answer this line

`golang  var proc = mod.NewProc("GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory")`

using 'GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory' will return the `installed`  ram,

if we change this line  to

`golang   mod.NewProc("GlobalMemoryStatusEx")`

'GlobalMemoryStatusEx' in the answers code will return the available memory

then a possible expression for memory used is

`installed - available`

For Linux

A scan of the file "/proc/meminfo"
the first 3 lines will possibly show tabulated fields with values

```
MemTotal:    24515792 kB
MemFree:        13053468 kB
MemAvailable:   19627908 kB
```

then  memory usage is
`MemTotal - MemAvailable`

there can be an [issue](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/776393) where the MemAvailable field is missing

in that case the following fields will probably exist

```
Buffers:          349596 kB
Cached:          7306116 kB
```

possible expression for memory used using the available fields in 'meminfo' would be

`MemTotal - MemFree - Buffers - Cached`

the [issue](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/776393) goes into the roles of the Buffers and cached fields

For Darwin
A similar approach as windows using the command  [vm_stat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14150722/1409784)